# pig local mode spill data issue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I am trying to solve this issue but unable to understand. The pig script in my Development machine ran on a 1.8 GB data file successfully.
When I am trying to run it in server it is stating that it cannot find a local device to spill data spill0.out
I have modified the pig.temp.Dir property in the pig.property file to point to a location having space..

error:
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for output/spill0.out

So how to find out where pig is spilling out the data and can we change the pig spill directory location as well somehow.

I  using pig in local mode.

Any ideas or suggestions or workarounds will be of great help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer.

We need to put the follwing to the $PIG_HOME/conf/pig.properties file

```
mapreduce.jobtracker.staging.root.dir
mapred.local.dir
pig.temp.dir
```

and then test.

This has helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Pig.
I'm not using Pig and I also have exactly the same error.
The problem seems to be more related to Hadoop. I also use it in local mode. I'm using Hadoop 2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with these answers, Pig (version 0.15.0) was still writing `pigbag*` files to `/tmp` dir so I just renamed my `/tmp` dir and created a symbolic link to the desired location like this:

```
sudo -s #change to root
cd /
mv tmp tmp_local
ln -s /desired/new/tmp/location tmp
chmod 1777 tmp
mv tmp_local/* tmp
```

Make sure there are no active applications writing to tmp folder at the time of running these commands.